# OpenVZ - vzdev kernel module issue

Tags: centos6, openvz, drbd

I am setting up a Centos 6.3 minimal server with openvz that replicates to another machine using DRBD.

I want all openvz data/files to be kept in a single /vz directory which is an LVM that I am syncing across with DRBD.

I managed to create symlinks so that `/etc/vz` points to `/vz/etc` and copied all the files there. I also moved `/etc/sysconfig/vz-scripts` to `/vz/vz-scripts` and put in a symbolic link there. I also made sure to update all the symbolic links withing the folders that I moved to ensure none were broken.

Unfortunately, if I reboot the server and then:

1. primary the drbd resource
2. mount /dev/drbd01 to /vz

whenever I try to create a virtual machine with vzcreate, I get the following error:

```
Unable to open /dev/vzctl: 
No such file or directory Please check that vzdev kernel module is loaded and you have sufficient permissions to access the file.
```

The error does not occur if I don't rearrange all the files way from /etc/ to /vz in the first place. I am guessing that these files need to be available/mounted on boot. Is there a way to get the 'kernel module' working after having manually primaried and mounted the drbd resource?

Answer (score 0):

Running this simple command before trying to install a container resolves the issue:

```
/etc/init.d/vz restart
```